# cmake не правильно определяет путь к компилятору

Tags: cmake

Cmake выводит \ вместо /.

```
G:\install\qt-everywhere-src-6.5.0-rc>cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\Qt-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\Users\New\Downloads\ninja-win\ninja.exe"
    CMake Warning:
      No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
      same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
      become a fatal error in future CMake releases.
    
    
    CMake Error at CMakeFiles/3.26.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1 (set):
      Syntax error in cmake code at
    
        G:/install/qt-everywhere-src-6.5.0-rc/CMakeFiles/3.26.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1
    
      when parsing string
    
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
    
      Invalid character escape '\P'.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)
    
    
    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Все проблемы указанны в тексте ошибки.

Comment: CMake понимает человеческую нотацию путей с прямым слэшем. Поэтому нет необходимости использовать мелкомягкую.